# Why aren't my nested lookarounds working correctly in my Perl substitution?

Tags: perl, substitution, regex-lookarounds

I have a Perl substitution which converts hyperlinks to lowercase:

```
's/(?<=<a href=")([^"]+)(?=")/\L$1/g'
```

I want the substitution to ignore any links which begin with a hash, for example I want it to change the path in `<a href="FooBar/Foo.bar">Foo Bar</a>` to lowercase but skip if it comes across `<a href="#Bar">Bar</a>`.

Nesting lookaheads to instruct it to skip these links isn't working correctly for me. This is the one-liner I've written:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(?<=<a href=" (?! (?<=<a href="#) ) )([^"]+)(?=")/\L$1/g' *;
```

Could anyone hint to me where I have gone wrong with this substitution? It executes just fine, but does not do anything.

Comment: I can't test this right now myself... Have you tried `(?<=<a href=")(?<!#)([^"]+)(?=")` (match everything that doesn't start with `#` but is preceded by `<a href="`) or maybe `(?<=<a href=")(?<!<a href="#)([^"]+)(?=")`? I don't think nesting is neccessary at all with lookarounds as they have zero length.

Comment: I read the article on lookarounds at PerlMonks so was trying to follow their examples - it's good to know that nesting may not be necessary though. Unfortunately those substitutions force lowercase on the hash links as well, but thank you for your guidance nonetheless.

Comment: By the way, you did put the spaces into your string for visibility, didn't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As near as I can tell, your initial regex will work just fine, if you add the condition that the first character in the link may not be a hash `#` or a double quote, e.g. `[^#"]`

```
s/(?<=<a href=")([^#"][^"]+)(?=")/\L$1/gi;
```

In the case you have links which do not start with a hash, e.g. `<a href="FooBar/Foo.bar#BarBar">Foo Bar</a>`, it becomes slightly more complicated:

```
s{(?<=<a href=")([^#"]+)(#[^"]+)*(?=")}{ lc($1) . ($2 // "") }gei;
```

We now have to evaluate the substitution, since otherwise we get undefined variable warnings when the optional anchor reference is not present.

Comment: Thank you TLP. Once again you prove that there is always a cleaner, simpler solution to a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need look-arounds, from what I see

```
use 5.010;
...

s/<a \s+ href \s* = \s* "\K([^#"][^"]*)"/\L$1"/gx;
```

`\K` means "keep" everything before it. It *amounts* to a variable-length look-behind.

[`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

> For various reasons \K may be significantly more efficient than the equivalent `(?<=...)` construct, and it is especially useful in situations where you want to efficiently remove something following something else in a string.

Comment: I'll stick with my current solution because I'm more familiar with the syntax, but thank you. It's always nice to learn the many ways of solving a single problem in Perl.